# pg_dump freezes on windows service application

Tags: postgresql, windows, dump, pg-dump

I have a system running over Tomcat which executes a backup batch job every day, it calls  `pg_dump.exe` from Java and stores its output to an SQL file.

When I'm executing Tomcat from the shell, it works perfectly, but when I start Tomcat as a Windows service the `pg_dump.exe` process stays there doing nothing, the SQL file is never written and the dump is never performed.

Is there any additional parameter or configuration required for Windows services? because it works without problems on a Unix-box.

**Update**: I'm using a Java class to call the operation.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(
          "C:/postgres9/bin/pg_dump.exe",
          "-U", "myuser",
          "-h" , "localhost",
          "mydb").start();
storeToFile( p.getInputStream() );
```

Specs:

- Tomcat 7.0.23
- Postgresql 9.1
- Windows 2008

Comment: How do you call `pg_dump.exe`?  The parameters passed to it and possibly the caller environment would be interesting.  From what you described so far, it can be anything (waiting for password is a usual suspect).

Comment: I thought that too, but why does it work without problems when I execute Tomcat from a shell? ...strange...

Comment: One thing I can think of is running from the application it does not see a variable that is present in the shell.

Comment: Aha! I see your point, the PGPASSWORD value might not be assigned. Let me check it.

Comment: You were right, the solution is here [How to run pg_dump from java](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2006-07/msg00197.php)

Comment: If you make an answer with the necessary information extracted from that post, you will earn at least 1 upvote :)

Comment: @dezso I have to wait 8 hours before doing it, but don't worry, I will. Thanks!!

Comment: Comment here when you do post an answer. I find that SO limitation quite irritating, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

[dezso](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6219/dezso) was right, the PGPASSWORD environment variable is present when executing Tomcat from a single shell, but not when it's started as a service. The solution is to put the value in the process environment:

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
      "C:/postgres9/bin/pg_dump.exe",
      "-U", "myuser",
      "-h" , "localhost",
      "mydb");

 Map<String, String> env = builder.environment();
 env.put("PGPASSWORD", "supersecret");

 Process p = builder.start();
 storeToFile( p.getInputStream() );
```

Solution source is here: [How to pg_dump from Java](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2006-07/msg00197.php)